# Transit in Korea without a visa

Tags: transit, china, south-korea

I am a USA valid visa holder. I want to go from Dhaka to China to Korea (2 days) to China (4 days) to Los Angeles. Then come back, fly to New York to China to Dhaka. Am I eligible to enter Korea without a visa?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're from Bangladesh? you would transit in China, then stay in South Korea for 2 days, then travel to again China and stay there for 4 days and then finally go to the USA?

Comment: A two day stay is generally too long to be considered as “transit”...

Comment: @Jacob How so?  Many countries allow multiday visa and visa-free transit.  In China, passport holders of 51 countries are allowed 72 hour Visa free transit at all their major airports and 144 hours at Shanghai, Jiangsu and Zhejiang.

Comment: @HanniballRun True, though few countries allow visa-free transit if you aren't actually in transit. If you fly China-Korea-China, you're just straight up visiting Korea, not transiting. Even China's liberal visa-free transit policy requires you to transit China on your way to a third country.

Answer (score 1):

From Timatic, the immigration database used by airlines, South Korea's [transit visa exception policy](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=BD&DE=SFO&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=ICN&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL) (click through to "For details, click here") is rather complicated:

> Visa Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of any country with a visa issued by Australia,
>
>   Austria, Belgium, Canada, Cyprus, Czech Rep., Denmark,   Estonia,
>     Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland,   Ireland (Rep.),
>     Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania,   Luxembourg, Malta,
>     Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland,   Portugal, Romania,
>     Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden,   Switzerland, USA or United
>     Kingdom if in transit through   Korea (Rep.) must:    -hold confirmed
>     onward tickets on flights departing within
>
>   30 days; when   -arriving from the country that issued the visa and 
>     departing to a third country. (YVR-ICN-DEL); or
>
>   -arriving from a third country and departing to the country
>
>   that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-YVR); or   -arriving from a third
>     country after having transited that   country for a maximum stay of 3
>     days, departing to the
>
>   country that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-SGN-ICN-YVR); or   -arriving
>     from a third country, traveling to another country   and staying there
>     for a maximum stay of 3 days, then   departing to the country that
>     issued the visa (e.g.
>
>   DEL-ICN-SGN-YVR).
>
>   - This does not apply to nationals of Afghanistan, Cuba,
>
>   Ghana, Iran, Iraq, Korea (Dem. People's Rep.), Kosovo    (Rep.),
>     Macedonia (FYROM), Nigeria, Sudan and Syria.
>
>   - This does not apply to passengers with a document issued by    the Palestinian Territory

As I understand this, you would not qualify and would need a visa. You are not transiting South Korea at all, but are visiting, going back and forth to China before going to the US. You would either need to receive a Korean visa or modify your itinerary to comply with these requirements.